# Swift: algorithm to append items in array

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I need to append items to an array using a specific algorithm:

with start index == 2 and separator == 5

for example input array:

```
["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]
```

for example output array:

```
["1", "1", "X", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "X", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "X", "1", "1", "1", "1"]
```

here is my code, but I can not find a way to make it work properly, looking forward to some help

```
var mixStartIndex = 2
var mixSeparator = 5

let array = ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]
var result = [AnyObject]()
for (index, item) in array.enumerated() {
    if (index > mixStartIndex+mixSeparator && index % mixSeparator == 0) || index == mixStartIndex {
        result.append("X" as AnyObject)
    }
    result.append(item as AnyObject)
}
print(result)
```

PS I am working with objects, just made example with strings for simplicity

Comment: why do you not use generics instead of AnyObject?

Comment: @PaFi I do not know how to use it and why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing to append the input array as a part of the output array

Try adding this

```
else
        {
            result.append(array[index])
        }
```

[image]

Update :
 changing the condition to `if (((index-mixStartIndex)%mixSeparator)==0 || index == mixStartIndex)` works for the fifth index

```
var mixStartIndex = 2
var mixSeparator = 6

func mix(array: [String]) -> [String] {
    guard !array.isEmpty else { return array }
    var result = [String]()
    for (index, _) in array.enumerated() {
        if (((index-mixStartIndex)%mixSeparator)==0 || index == mixStartIndex) {
            result.append("X")
     }
        else
        {
            result.append(array[index])
        }
}
    return result
}
```

[image]

Comment: count your number of "1", it's 7, not 5

Comment: changed you answer: for (index, item) in array.enumerated() {
        if (((index-mixStartIndex)%mixSeparator)==0 || index == mixStartIndex) {
            result.append("X")
        }
        
            result.append(item)
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

A functional solution to create an array where elements are ***inserted*** into the resulting array:

```
let result: [String] = array.enumerated().reduce(into:[]) { acc, elm in
    let tempo = ((elm.offset - 2) % 5 == 0 ? ["X"] : []) + [elm.element]
    acc.append(contentsOf: tempo)
}
```

If instead of inserting you'd like to **replace** the elements :

```
let result = array.enumerated().map {
    ($0.offset - 2) % 6 == 0 ? "X" : $0.element
}
```

---

### Array.insert(_:at:)

We could use the built-in function [`Array.insert(_:at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126951-insert)

```
let newCount = array.count > 2 ? array.count + 1 + (array.count - 3) / 6 : array.count

var index = 2
let mixSeparator = 6

var result = array

while index < newCount {
    result.insert("X", at: index)
    index += mixSeparator
}
```

But that would be inefficient, not only because you the whole array and then start inserting, but also because `insert(_:at:)` is an O(n) operation. Meaning that all the elements after the index of insertion should be shifted. A more efficient solution would be to do the insertion iteratively :

---

### Iterative insert

Here is a pretty easy to understand iterative solution :

```
let array = ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]

var result = array
let x = "X"

let startIndex = 2
let step = 6

var count = 0
var index = 2

while index < array.count {
    result[index] = x
    count += 1
    index += step
}

result.append(contentsOf: Array(repeating: "1", count: count))
```

Or, if you'd like to create the `result` array in one go :

```
let newCount = array.count > 2 ? array.count + 1 + (array.count - 3) / 6 : array.count

var result = [String]()
result.reserveCapacity(newCount)

let startIndex = 2
let step = 6

var nextIndexToPutX = startIndex
var index = 0

while index < newCount {
    if index == nextIndexToPutX {
        result.append("X")
        nextIndexToPutX += step
    } else {
        result.append("1")
    }
    index += 1
}
```

---

### Replace iteratively

```
var result = [String]()
result.reserveCapacity(array.count)

var nextIndexToPutX = 2
let step = 6

var index = 0

while index < array.count {
    if index == nextIndexToPutX {
        result.append("X")
        nextIndexToPutX += step
    } else {
        result.append(array[index])
    }
    index += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works and is simpler than the accepted answer:

```
extension Array {
    func example(start: Index, seperator: Index, insert: Element) -> [Element] {
        var result = self
        var index = start
        while index < result.count {
            result.insert(insert, at: index)
            index += seperator + 1
        }
        return result
    }

    // a functional solution
    func example2(start: Index, seperator: Index, insert: Element) -> [Element] {
        return self.enumerated().flatMap { offset, element in
            offset == start || offset > start && (offset - start) % seperator == 0 ? [insert, element] : [element]
        }
    }
}

print(array.example(start: mixStartIndex, seperator: mixSeparator, insert: "X"))
print(array.example2(start: mixStartIndex, seperator: mixSeparator, insert: "X"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one, a little more straightforward.

```
  let array = ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]

  let result = array.enumerated().flatMap{ ($0.offset - 1)  % 5 == 0 ? [$0.element, "X"] : [$0.element]}

  print(result)
```